# Calculating probability

Tags: probability

> There are six socks in a drawer. The socks are of two colors: black and white. If you draw two socks randomly, the probability that you get white socks is $\frac{2}{3}$. What is the probability of getting black socks, when two socks are drawn at a time?

There is no detail about the number of white and black socks. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $k$ white socks, the probability of getting two white socks equals:

$$\frac{k}{6} \cdot \frac{k-1}{5} = \frac{k(k-1)}{30} = \frac{2}{3} \iff k(k-1) = 20 \iff k=5$$

Since there are five white socks, it is impossible to draw more than one black sock. As such, the probability of getting two black socks is 0. The probability of getting one black sock and one white sock equals:

$$\frac{{5 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}}{6 \choose 2} = \frac{5}{15} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Indeed, $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{0}{3} = 1.$

Comment: Thank you @jvdhooft .What if the probability of drawing a white sock pair TWICE is 2/3 ?

Comment: @Priyanga.K You mean drawing four white socks without replacement? In that case you would have to solve $k$ for $\frac{k \choose 4}{n \choose 4} = \frac{2}{3}$. Do note that there are no valid solutions for $n=6$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $0$: out of $15$ possible unordered couples of socks, you know that $10$ are made by white socks. It means that only $5$ possible pairs of socks contain a black sock. It can only be true if there is one black sock and $5$ white socks.